# ASP.net can't get font size right

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts, size, font-size

I'm drawing labels to an image file.  It all works perfectly, except the font size.

```
gfx.DrawString(
    thisTempLabel.LabelText,
    new System.Drawing.Font(
        thisTempLabel.LabelFont,
        (float)thisTempLabel.fontSize
    ),
    Brushes.Black,
    new PointF(thisTempLabel.x, thisTempLabel.y)
);
```

Problem is my users pick font sizes in PX, and `System.Drawing.Font` requires an EM size.  I don't know how to resolve this!

Can I render the text using pixels?

Comment: PX to EM converter? - http://pxtoem.com/

Comment: @Martin thanks, but I need a general formula I think :s

Comment: I agree with Martin, just convert the px values to EM and you should be good to go.

Comment: visit his link in his comment. It gives you a list of values, I'm sure you could build a formula from the data provided.

Comment: I'd rather just be able to define it in PC in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use 1 em = 16 pixels.  So:

```
14px: 1 / 16 * 14 = 
13px: 1 / 16 * 13 = 
100px: 1 / 16 * 100 =
```

Comment: These are all coming out tiny... `((float)thisTempLabel.fontSize) * (float)0.0625)`

Answer (score 5):

Finally figured it out for if anyone has same problem:

```
System.Drawing.Font MyFont = new System.Drawing.Font(
    thisTempLabel.LabelFont,
    ((float)thisTempLabel.fontSize),
    FontStyle.Regular,
    GraphicsUnit.Pixel
);
```

GraphicsUnit.Pixel does it!